# Connect to VM on Fiware Lab over SSH: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh, timeout, virtual-machine, openstack, fiware

I create an instance in fiware lab.
I add the port 22 to a security group,then i associate a floating IP to my instance.
But when i try to connect to my instance using ssh, i get the message {connection time out}.

theses screenshots describe my configuration
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSSmB.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y76zI.png

NB: I don't have any problem with the proxy.
So, what can do about this problem?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you open ICMP port and try to ping to your instance. Are you able to ping your instance?

Such failures could occur if your instance is down(failed to boot up properly), or it failed to get IP address from DHCP server or static ip-address, or if the openvswitch-agent is down. I would suggest to first try with ping and see if you can reach your instance. Alternatively, you can login to your instance using VNC console/dashboard and see if the networking is fine or not.

To create default password for instance, you can specify it in cloud-init script. This is available in "post creation" -> "direct input". Just put this in the box there:-

```
#cloud-config
hostname: xyz-vm
fqdn: test.com
ssh_pwauth: false
password: myownpassword
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to open ICMP port, but I still can't ping to VM.
concerning VNC, I can't sign in to my instance, because I can't use the key pair to authenticate.
so I can't even work with my instance.

Comment: Here two screenshots to explain my situation: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/569847Capture.jpg http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/345432Capture1.jpg

Comment: You can create a default username and password for your instances. You just need to provide cloud-init configuration when you are launching the instance. Check the answer above to see what needs to be provided to create default password.

Comment: Or launch a cirros instance. It has a fixed username and password. Test to see if its working there or not.